# getting year from date returned from ajax in the form of json

Tags: json, jquery

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "file.php",
        data: {id: sampleval},
        success: function(data)
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {   
                    currentTime = data[i]['hire'];
                    var d1 = Date.parse(""+currentTime+"");
                    alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy'));
                    var d2 = d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy');
                    alert((new date).getFullYear - d2.getFullYear());
                }
            }
        });
```

`data[i]['hire']` is a date. with format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I am having a hard time getting only the year. What I wanted was to display the number of years an employee has been on the company.

Answer (score 0):

This should give the difference in years: `alert(new Date().getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear());`